# How do I make an `object!` from a `map!`

Tags: red

I have a `map!`: `#(a: 1)` and want to convert it to an equivalent `object!` like: `[a: 1]`.

Comment: Not every map! can be converted to an object: `object body-of m: #("1" "test")` will generate an empty object, while `object body-of m: #(a: test)` will fail with `Script Error: test has no value`

Answer (score 2):

Generate the object spec by converting the map to a block first. The map keys must all be `word!`s.

```
>> object to-block #(a: 5)
== make object! [
    a: 5
]
```

Comment: May or may not be what you'd expect when you have stuff nested: `#(a: 5 b: #(c: 3))`

Comment: you can also use `body-of`